# how to format the sum two dimensional arrays with formatter?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I have to add the votes per state of the 2008 elections on a 2 dimensional array, but when I run the code it sums only the first row and then keeps adding itself to the previous sum 51 times to the right side  like this:

- State       Obama      McCain       Other       Total by state
- Alabama      813479     1266546       19794          2099819   2426016  72985 etc...
- Alaska      123594      193841        8762           2099819   2426016  72985 etc...

But i needed to add the total votes on each state only once per row.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
{  
  // TODO code application logic here
  File election = new File("voting_2008.txt");  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(election);  

  String[] states = new String[51];  
  int[][]votes = new int[51][4];  
  int[] Totalbystate = new int[votes.length];  

  for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)  
  {  
    states[s] = sc.nextLine();  
  }  

  for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)  
  {  
    for(int s=0; s < 51; s++)  
    {  
      votes[s][c] = sc.nextInt();  
    }  
  }  

  Formatter fmt = new Formatter();  
  fmt.format("%20s%12s%12s%12s%21s", "State", "Obama", "McCain", "Other", "Total by state");  
  System.out.println(fmt);  
  for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)  
  {  
    fmt = new Formatter();  
    fmt.format("%20s", states[s]);  
    System.out.print(fmt);  
    for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)  
    {  
      fmt = new Formatter();  
      fmt.format("%12d", votes[s][c]);  
      System.out.print(fmt);  
    }  
    int sum =0;  
    for(int row=0; row < votes.length; row++)  
    {  
      for (int col=0; col < votes[row].length; col++)  
      {  
        sum = sum + votes[row][col];  
      }  
      fmt = new Formatter();  
      fmt.format("%21d", sum);  
      System.out.print(fmt);  
    }  

    System.out.println();  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I run the code it sums only the first row and then keeps adding itself to the previous sum 51 times to the right side like this:

Look at your code:

```
int sum =0;
for(int row=0; row < votes.length; row++)
{   
    for (int col=0; col < votes[row].length; col++)
    {
        sum = sum + votes[row][col];
    }
    fmt = new Formatter();
    fmt.format("%21d", sum);
    System.out.print(fmt);  
}
```

Look at where you're setting `sum` to 0. Now think about where you *should* be setting it to 0...

Comment: awesome i moved to the inner loop and now its adding perfectly. however it keeps putting the sums on the right side 51 times instead of under the column total by state. do you have any advice for that? Thanks

Comment: @user1663414: You're *really* not going to be able to show this in a comment. But this sounds like it's now a separate question. You need to work out how to separate your concerns.

Comment: ok. thank you. I'm going to ask againg with the right summation thanks.