# how to correctly use formatter on a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, formatter

I have to add the sum of the rows of a two dimensional array in a column to the right side. however, when I run the code it adds the sum of all the rows in every column until it reaches the end.  like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QQZT.png the sum is right but is suppose to go down and just once per row.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    File election = new File("voting_2008.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(election);

    String[] states = new String[51];
    int[][]votes = new int[51][4];
    int[] Totalbystate = new int[votes.length];

    for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
    {
        states[s] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        for(int s=0; s < 51; s++)
        {
            votes[s][c] = sc.nextInt();

        }

    }
    Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
    fmt.format("%20s%12s%12s%12s%21s", "State", "Obama", "McCain", "Other", "Total by state");
    System.out.println(fmt);
    for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
    {
       fmt = new Formatter();
       fmt.format("%20s", states[s]);
       System.out.print(fmt);
       for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)
       {
           fmt = new Formatter();
           fmt.format("%12d", votes[s][c]);
           System.out.print(fmt);

       }

       for(int row=0; row < votes.length; row++)
       {   
            int sum =0;
           for (int col=0; col < votes[row].length; col++)
           {
              sum = sum + votes[row][col];

           }
          fmt = new Formatter();
            fmt.format("%21d", sum);
            System.out.print(fmt);  
       }


       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You came again with the same question?? You could have asked for clarification there only.. In fact you accepted the answer there..

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format the sum two dimensional arrays with formatter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804420/how-to-format-the-sum-two-dimensional-arrays-with-formatter)

Comment: sorry but I was told by a user that this was a different question

Comment: @user1663414.. See my update to get the problem in your code.. I have suggested a change that will work for you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for(int row=0; row < votes.length; row++)
   {   
        int sum =0;
        for (int col=0; col < votes[row].length; col++)
         {
          sum = sum + votes[row][col];

        }
        fmt = new Formatter();
        fmt.format("%21d", sum);  
        System.out.print(fmt); // You are not printing newline after each vote..
   }
```

Try using : - `System.out.println(fmt);` in place of commented code..

**UPDATE** :-  **Don't do the above change**.. Will not work.. Do the following change indeed.

Here's is the problem.. You're printing your `total no of votes`, 51 * 51 times.. You're having this loop inside another loop, which is already running 51 times..

So, **to solve your problem**.. Remove the outer loop from the above code, and just keep it like this: -

```
   //for(int row=0; row < votes.length; row++) // Remove this loop
   //{ // Remove this

        int sum =0;
        for (int col=0; col < votes[s].length; col++)
         {
          sum = sum + votes[s][col];

        }
        fmt = new Formatter();
        fmt.format("%21d", sum);  
        System.out.print(fmt);
   //} // Remove this also..
```

Value of `s` you are getting from the outer-most loop ..

**UPDATE**: - **In case you want sum of all the votes.. For all column..**

```
int totalSum = 0;    // Declare a variable outside it..
for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)   // This is the place where the loop started
{
   fmt = new Formatter();
   fmt.format("%20s", states[s]);
   System.out.print(fmt);

   // Other inner loops

    int sum =0;   // Your innerloop that calculates sum of each state..
    for (int col=0; col < votes[s].length; col++)
     {
      sum = sum + votes[s][col];

    }

    totalSum += sum;   // Add sum to `totalSum`
    fmt = new Formatter();
    fmt.format("%21d", sum);  
    System.out.print(fmt);

    // Continue with the outer loop
}
```

Comment: when I removed the loop as you mentioned, the variable row disappears which gives me the "cannot find symbol" "variable row" error. Thanks.

Comment: @user1663414.. Oh. Sorry.. I forgot to mention.. replace `row` with `s`.. the variable of outer most loop

Comment: i was wondering what if i want to sum the columns as well? how would you do it? Thanks...

Comment: @user1663414.. In that case, have another variable `totalSum` outside the outer most loop :- `for(s = 0; s < 51; s++)`, and add the sum you obtained to that.. after the place where you are printing `sum`..

Comment: @user1663414.. See my latest update.. I took parts of your code. You need to fit it at appropriate place by matching the loops..